# Flutter How to remove overscroll effect from ListView

Tags: flutter

How to remove overscroll effect from ListView (round overlay on Android, bounce on iOS)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 3,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text('Some text');
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks. Here's more text to compensate code/text ratio

Comment: Inside your `ListView` widget, add `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`